# H.264 profiles support of latest Flash Player (v11.6)

Tags: flash-player, profile, h.264

Does anyone know what profiles of H.264 videos latest Flash Player(currently 11.6) supports?
Half an hour googling only gives [an article from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/articles/h264_encoding.html) exactly about my question, which is old, and [a page of ActionScript 3.0 reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/H264Profile.html), which provides seemingly contradicted info(no HIGH constant?).

Thanks.

Comment: Mmm... looks like no one knows it. I have searched it for extra hours using multiple search engine, but no luck. Perhaps I should conduct an experiment on Flash Player using MP4 files with each profile...

Answer (score 0):

Flash Player supports h264: Baseline, Main, High, and High 10. 
( Source: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/articles/h264_encoding.html )

Comment: That's the same article as the one I provided... No difference for current version?